# Catch output stream of xsl result-document

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I need a way to interfere in writting xsl result documents to avoid writting them to file system. Right now my template is writting to a temporary directory, and then i zip that directory. I want to do that whitout writting to file system. I am using saxon procesor. A solution that is using just standard java libraries is perfered. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I found this class for .net saxon api http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/IResultDocumentHandler.html
I need something equivalent for java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement interface `net.sf.saxon.OutputURIResolver` 
http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/OutputURIResolver.html
You can redirect output in resolve method however you like. In my case this is how implemented class looks like.

```
public class ZipOutputURIReslover implements OutputURIResolver{

    private ZipOutputStream zipOut;

    public ZipOutputURIReslover(ZipOutputStream zipOut) {
        super();
        this.zipOut = zipOut;
    }

    public void close(Result arg0) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            zipOut.closeEntry();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Result resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(href));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new StreamResult(zipOut);
    }
}
```

After this you need to register `net.sf.saxon.OutputURIResolver` to  trasnformer factory.

```
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.zip"));
factory.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/outputURIResolver", new ZipOutputURIReslover(zipOut));
```

When you load your template and run transformation all xsl:result-documents will be written directly to zipOutputStream.
Answer was found here http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/discussion/94027/thread/9ee79dea/#70a9/6fef

Comment: `factory.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/outputURIResolver", new ZipOutputURIReslover(zipOut));`

can be actually replaced with: 

`transformer.getUnderlyingController().setOutputURIResolver(outputURIResolver);`, where `transformer` is an instance of `XsltTransformer` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new StreamResult(ByteArrayOutputStream())` to catch xslt output, if you don't want to write to files, and then you can save memory data from byte array to zip file using this approach [In Java: How to zip file from byte[] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357851/in-java-how-to-zip-file-from-byte-array)

Comment: Problem is i dont need to catch xslt output from "transform" function. That output is allways empty document. I need to catch output stream of <xsl:result-document> function that is called inside template. I need somehow to interfere with saxons handling of this template function and saxons handling of those output streams. File names are relevant, and i dont know how many result documents this template will produce. It depends on input xml document.

Answer (score 0):

Note that recent versions of Saxon require that the href (URI) is unique.  Thus the system ID of the stream in the output resolver must also be unique.

For example:

1. Specify the result document href values in the stylesheet

   ```
   <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" method="text">
   ```
2. Create the output resolver

   ```
   public class ZipOutputURIReslover implements OutputURIResolver{

       private ZipOutputStream zipOut;

       public ZipOutputURIReslover(ZipOutputStream zipOut) {
           super();
           this.zipOut = zipOut;
       }

       public void close(Result arg0) throws TransformerException {
           try {
               zipOut.closeEntry();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       public Result resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
           try {
               zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(href));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Result result = new StreamResult(zipOut);
           // Must ensure the stream is given a unique ID
           result.setSystemId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Attach the output resolver to the transformer

   ```
   ZipOutputURIResolver outputResolver = new ZipOutputURIResolver(outputStream);
   // Controller is the Saxon implementation of the JAXP Transformer
   ((Controller) transformer).setOutputURIResolver(outputResolver);
   ```