# Handle Stream in Custom URI Resolver for Saxon Parser

Tags: function, xslt, external, saxon

I have to process an xml against an xslt with result-document that create many xml.
As suggested here:
[Catch output stream of xsl result-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029968/catch-output-stream-of-xsl-result-document)

I wrote my personal URI Resolver:

```
public class CustomOutputURIResolver implements OutputURIResolver{

    private File directoryOut;

    public CustomOutputURIResolver(File directoryOut) {
        super();
        this.directoryOut = directoryOut;
    }

    public void close(Result arg0) throws TransformerException {

    }

    public Result resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
       FileOutputStream fout = null;
       try {
            File f = new File(directoryOut.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + href + File.separator + href + ".xml");
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new StreamResult(fout);
    }

}
```

that get the output directory and then saves here the files.

But then when I tested it in a junit I had some problems in the clean-up phase, when trying to delete the created files and noticed that the FileOutputStream fout is not well handled.
Trying to solve the problem gave me some thoughts:

First I came out with this idea:

```
public class CustomOutputURIResolver implements OutputURIResolver{

    private File directoryOut;
    private FileOutputStream fout

    public CustomOutputURIResolver(File directoryOut) {
        super();
        this.directoryOut = directoryOut;
        this.fout = null;
    }

    public void close(Result arg0) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            if (null != fout) {
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
                fout = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public Result resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {

        try {
            if (null != fout) {
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        fout = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(directoryOut.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + href + File.separator + href + ".xml");
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new StreamResult(fout);
    }

}
```

So the fileOutputStream is closed anytime another one is opened.
But:

1) I don't like this solution very much

2) what if this function is called in a multithread process? (I'm not very skilled about Saxon parsing, so i really don't know..)

3) Is there a chance to create and handle one FileOutputStream for each resolve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason close() takes a Result argument is so that you can identify which stream to close. Why not:

```
public void close(Result arg0) throws TransformerException {
    try {
        if (arg0 instanceof StreamResult) {
            OutputStream os = ((StreamResult)arg0).getOutputStream();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

From Saxon-EE 9.5, xsl:result-document executes in a new thread, so it's very important that the OutputURIResolver should be thread-safe. Because of this change, from 9.5 an OutputURIResolver must implement an additional method getInstance() which makes it easier to manage state: if your newInstance() method actually creates a new instance, then there will be one instance of the OutputURIResolver for each result document being processed, and it can hold the output stream and close it when requested.

Comment: that's right.. for some reason I was thinking that the close function were called only at the end of the entire process and I didn't pay attention to its argument.. now I've arranged the code and it worked nice, Thanks!